# SQL - AS - table doesn't exist - 1146

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1146

My query is:

```
SELECT temp.pid FROM 
(SELECT postid, date FROM swapping AS s, post AS p 
WHERE s.mid='2' AND p.postid=s.postid)  AS temp 
WHERE temp.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM temp)
```

I receive #1146 - Table 'databasename.temp' doesn't exist

How can I make it work?
 Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to select the last "pid", in terms of "date", where s.mid='2'

Try this (after you figure out where pid comes from and correct the first line)

```
SELECT [s? or maybe p?].pid
FROM swapping s INNER JOIN post p ON p.postid=s.postid
WHERE s.mid = '2'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT(0,1)
```

You might also need to alias the date column in the order by line.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Maybe you know why my query is wrong?

Comment: - table TEMP doesn't exist for the subquery SELECT MAX(date) FROM temp (the alias is outside, you'd have to do select MAX(date) from aRealTableOrQuery)
- temp.pid is not defined.  Only the fields that you select within the query aliased 'temp' will be available to select via temp.somefield.  So your inner query needs to SELECT the pid field
- temp.date might give an error, some (all?) database types require the use of the original alias here (so, s.date or p.date)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your column incorrect...

```
SELECT temp.pid  FROM  ( SELECT  postid, ...
```

should be

```
SELECT temp.postid  FROM  ( SELECT  postid, ...
```

Comment: @lvil, then can you show us more of the structures to know what is from where?

Answer (score 0):

@DRapp hit the nail on the head at least. You haven't selected 'pid' (if that column exists in either the swapping or post table) in your sub selection that your referring to as temp so it would throw some type of error there.